# How to convert to "end-of-month"?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time

I have several dataframes that currently have all end-of-month data.

I now used following script to import Finance data:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import urllib.request  

urllib.request.urlretrieve(  
    'http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=^GSPC&a=4&b=1&c=2013&d=5&e=1&f=2016&g=m&ignore=.csv',
    'gspc.csv'
)

table = pd.read_csv('gspc.csv')

    Date    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Adj Close
49  2012-05-01  1,398   1,415   1,292   1,310   4158095900  1,310
48  2012-06-01  1,310   1,363   1,267   1,362   4103472300  1,362
47  2012-07-02  1,362   1,392   1,325   1,379   3663113300  1,379
```

As I said, I need to get this data into end-of-month.
I.e.

```
    Date    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Adj Close
49  2012-05-31  1,398   1,415   1,292   1,310   4158095900  1,310
48  2012-06-30  1,310   1,363   1,267   1,362   4103472300  1,362
47  2012-07-31  1,362   1,392   1,325   1,379   3663113300  1,379
```

I tried

```
table['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(table['Date'])
table.set_index('Date').resample('M')
table
```

but weren't successful, though "M" should be "[month end frequency](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html)".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be the thing you're looking for

```
table['Date'] = table['Date'] - pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd()
```

Comment: I think it should be: `table.Date -= pd.offsets.MonthEnd()`

Comment: @Rnaldinho, `a -= b` is a short form of `a = a - b`

Comment: @MaxU: Now the issue is that it obviously merges index values such as "2012-04-30 00:00:00", though it should only be "2012-04-30"

Comment: @Rnaldinho, try this: `table.Date = table.Date.dt.normalize()`

Comment: @Rnaldinho, why did you "unaccept" this answer? I think it did answer your question, no?

Comment: I did, clicked too fast :) It should be everything fine now. Also, the normalize() seems to be a solution here!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just want to convert the dates in the index from beginning of month to end of month, i.e. Dec 1st to Dec 31st. You can try resample and last:

```
table.set_index('Date').resample('M').last()
```

Comment: This is wrong - the answer by Ivan above is correct.  .last() is for how the resampling is done - ie. using the last value in the month rather than maybe the mean with .mean() or max with .max()

Comment: @GoPackGo have you tried my code and see whether it works? I can get the expected numbers  (i.e. month end prices with month end dates) with this code.

Comment: the user said .resample('M') wasn't working.   Adding .last() doesn't have anything to do with getting you the last day of the month.  What if the user wanted the last date of the month with the average or max value of the month?

Comment: Well, the user also said he wanted to get this data into end-of-month, which is exactly what this code piece does.